# When Calling a view model class Attempt to read from field 'androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData on a null object reference android MVVM Java

Tags: java, android, android-mvvm

I am developing the project in mvvm architecture. Here I have a class like create profile and also another class like edit profile. Edit profile is a fragment class. here I created a same view model class for both the create profile and edit profile fragment classes.In edit profile class when I call view model class getting null pointer exception.

In Edit Profile Fragment Class I am calling the view model class

```
public class EditProfileFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private UserService userService;
    private String eId;

    private final static String TAG = "EditProfile";

    @Override
    protected int getFragmentLayoutID() {
        return R.layout.activity_create_profile;
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isSubscribedToEvents() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<ProfileVM> getVMClass() {
        return ProfileVM.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getVMVariableId() {
        return BR.profileVM;
    }
@Override
    protected void init() {
            userService = getApiClient().create(UserService.class);
            ProfileVM profileVM = (ProfileVM) getViewModel();
            UserDTO userDTO = getUserDao().getUserDetails();
            eId = userDTO.getId();
            Log.d(TAG,"editprofileenigma"+eId);
            Log.d(TAG,"userdtoedit"+userDTO);
            userService.getUserProfile(eId);// this is the api call
            profileVM.user.setValue(userDTO); // here iam getting null pointer exception
            profileVM.individual.setValue(getUserDao().getUserIndividual());
            profileVM.individualProfile.setValue(getUserDao().getIndividualProfile());
         profileVM.individualAttributePermission.setValue(getUserDao().getIndividualAttributePermission());
        }
}
```

My View Model Class

```
@Bindable
    public MutableLiveData<String> heading = new MutableLiveData<>("Create Profile");
    @Bindable
    public MutableLiveData<UserDTO> user = new MutableLiveData<>(new UserDTO());
    @Bindable
    public MutableLiveData<Individual> individual = new MutableLiveData<>(new Individual());
    @Bindable
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> isDemographicExpanded = new MutableLiveData<>(true);
    @Bindable
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> isLiveNInterestExpanded = new MutableLiveData<>(true);
    @Bindable
    public MutableLiveData<IndividualProfile> individualProfile = new MutableLiveData<>(new IndividualProfile());
    @Bindable
    public MutableLiveData<IndividualAttributePermission> individualAttributePermission = new MutableLiveData<>(new IndividualAttributePermission());
    @Bindable
    public MutableLiveData<ProfileSwitchModel> profileSwitchModel = new MutableLiveData<>(new ProfileSwitchModel(new IndividualAttributePermission()));



    private Individual getIndividual() {
        return individual.getValue()==null? new Individual() : individual.getValue();
    }

    private IndividualProfile getIndividualProfiles() {
        return individualProfile.getValue()==null? new IndividualProfile() : individualProfile.getValue();
    }

    private IndividualAttributePermission getIndividualAttributePermissions() {
        return individualAttributePermission.getValue()==null? new IndividualAttributePermission() : individualAttributePermission.getValue();
    }
```

Comment: for this situation, you can define it  in activity, then use it in other fragment

Comment: @Lenoarod I didn't get the point. Create Profile is separate activity and I am using the same view model

Comment: Is it the same viewModel instance?

Comment: @Lenoarod yes it is same

Comment: you use it in the different fragment, so I think the ViewModel is not the same instance. you define it in the baseFragment.  it still not the same instance

Comment: the class is different from the instance, you should know that